# Problems with building SSToolKit and SSOAuthKit

Tags: ios, static, sstoolkit

I'm trying to build Sam Soffes' TwitterDemo which uses SSToolKit and SSOAuthKit. I get 6 errors and 1 warning. Here they are:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSSOAuthKit.a(SSAddressBarTextFieldBackgroundView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSSOAuthKit.a(SSAddressBarTextFieldBackgroundView.o)
  "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn", referenced from:
      -[SSAddressBarTextFieldBackgroundView _setupAnimation] in libSSOAuthKit.a(SSAddressBarTextFieldBackgroundView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAKeyframeAnimation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSSOAuthKit.a(SSAnimatedImageView.o)
  "_kCAAnimationDiscrete", referenced from:
      -[SSAnimatedImageView _animationWithName:images:repeatCount:delegate:] in libSSOAuthKit.a(SSAnimatedImageView.o)
  "_kCAFillModeForwards", referenced from:
      -[SSAnimatedImageView _animationWithName:images:repeatCount:delegate:] in libSSOAuthKit.a(SSAnimatedImageView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And warning:

```
'UIImage' may not respond to '+imageNamed:bundle:'
```

I think the problem is that libSSToolkit.a and libSSOAuthKit.a haven't built. I tried to build them, but I failed - they are still red.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you need to add QuartzCore to your project.

Comment: I can see its added in my app. But still its not building..:S